# How can getLoadTime plugin be implemented in Adobe DTM?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Where do I make the initial function call to `s_getLoadTime()`. My library is being managed by Adobe.

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/getLoadTime.html

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Add the plugin and timer start code**

First, you need a **Page Load Rule** that is set to trigger at "Top of Page".  If you already have an existing rule that triggers every page load at top of page, you can use that. If you do not, then create a new one.

Then, in the **Javascript / Third Party Tags** section, click on "Add New Script". Set the **Type** to "Sequential Javascript" and check the **Execute Globally** option.

In the code box, paste the following code:

```
// this is for older browser support
var inHeadTS=(new Date()).getTime();

// plugin
function s_getLoadTime(){if(!window.s_loadT){var b=new Date().getTime(),o=window.performance?performance.timing:0,a=o?o.requestStart:window.inHeadTS||0;s_loadT=a?Math.round((b-a)/100):''}return s_loadT}

// call plugin first time 
s_getLoadTime();
```

Click on **Save Code** and then **Save Rule**.

**Step 2: Make the 2nd call to plugin and assign to Adobe Analytics variables**

Next, you need a **Page Load Rule** that is set to trigger at "Bottom of Page".  If you already have an existing rule that triggers every page load at bottom of page, you can use that. If you do not, then create a new one.

Then, go to **Conditions > Rule Conditions > Criteria** and from the dropdown select **Data > Custom** and click "Add Criteria".  In the code box, add the following:

```
_satellite.setVar('loadTime',s_getLoadTime());
return true;
```

Then within **Adobe Analytics** section of the rule, you can set your prop and/or eVar to `%loadTime%`.

**Note:** Using a rule set to trigger at "Onload" will technically be more accurate. However, DTM does not currently offer ability to trigger Adobe Analytics Onload (options are only for top or bottom of page), so if you set the rule to "Onload" it will trigger after AA has made a request so your variables will not be populated and sent in that request. If you *really* want to keep the accuracy then you will need to explore other options, such as implementing AA as a 3rd party script so that you have more control over when it triggers.

Click on **Save Rule** and then Approve/Publish once you have tested.

Answer (score 2):

The question should really be, "Why should the getLoadTime() plugIn be used, ever?".  Yasho, I started with the same question that you had and blindly implemented the plugIn in Adobe DTM following the instructions at https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/getLoadTime.html

Only after starting to analyze the data did I look into the plugIn to see what it does.

Below is the beautified code of the plugIn:

```
function s_getLoadTime() {
    if (!window.s_loadT) {
        var b = new Date().getTime(),
            o = window.performance ? performance.timing : 0,
            a = o ? o.requestStart : window.inHeadTS || 0;
        s_loadT = a ? Math.round((b - a) / 100) : ''
    }
    return s_loadT
}
```

So, basically the function records s_loadT once and only once.  The first call (way at the top of the page) sets the value and any subsequent call to the function will return that same value since it has been persisted in window.s_loadT

Scratch your head a bit and ask the obvious question, "So what does this measure anyway?"  Best case, it measures the difference between window.performace.timing.requestStart and the timeStamp when the function was first called.  Worst case it measures the difference between a timestamp set in the head of the document by javascript (and that difference could very well be a negative number).  Or even worse if 'a' resolves to 0, you'll just get 'b' which will be a huge number.

If you are following the directions and calling getLoadTime() up high in the document (DTM page top rule), you're really just be measuring how long it takes to fire a page top rule.  If you put the first call into the top of your s_code.js, you're just measuring how long it takes to load (and execute) s_code.js

Comment: So did you arrive at at result that provides greater accuracy than the s_getLoadTime function? The s.performance timing plugin looks promising https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/performanceTiming.html